# Dynamically create buttons inside of UIView

Tags: ios, swift

I currently trying to implement a dropdown menu. The content of this menu is supposed to be several buttons. The amount of the buttons is determined by the size of the struct array `carsArray`.

The title of the button shall be each structs value `name`:

```
for n in 0...carsArray.count - 1 {
    button.setTitle(carsArray[n].name, .normal)
}
```

This menu shall slide in from above. To do this, I created a UIView - **how can I dynamically create as many buttons as there are entries to the `carsArray` inside of the UIView?**

Additionally, am I right to assume that with every entry the UIView's size have to adjusted? If so, how to also do this with every entry? Or do I have to create a table view to do so?

Is there another, easier way to create such a dropdown menu? Maybe with already from Apple given classes?

Comment: I would use a simple collectionView where you pass your data. Each cell then can have a unique button label, which is tailored by the datasource

Comment: You can use a `UITableView` with button inside cell.

Comment: @Augusto how can I adjust tableview's size with every added button?

Comment: You can set the tableview's size on `cellForRowAt` method.

Answer (score 0):

The way this can be achieved is by using a UITableView. To implement the opening and closing of dropdown, you would need to add or remove the cells or animate the height of UITableView. To close, you would make the height as 1 row height and to expand, you would make it maximum height or total number of rows height.

This is the [library](https://github.com/kerry/UGDropDown)  that I created a few months ago for one of my apps. It uses a UITableView to create the drop down. Have a look at this.

Let me know if you face any problem using this. Would be happy to fix.

Comment: While your library may be helpful, it's not really appropriate as an answer. Links can die, and it doesn't provide any coding information. This is more suited to a comment. See [answer].

Comment: @DonMag Thanks for the correction. I have edited my answer to add implementation details as well.

Comment: @DonMag I have fixed the answer, can you please remove your downvote?